# skip permission to connect to usb Accessory

Tags: android, usb

I don't want to take permission to connect to USB accessory as i want to connect to a specific USB accessory. Is it possible . As i have read on android.com as follows

> Note: If your application uses an intent filter to discover accessories as they're connected, it >automatically receives permission if the user allows your application to handle the intent. If not, >you must request permission explicitly in your application before connecting to the accessory.

So is it possible to do so. Please help.

---

Thanks 
Gaurav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the intent with this code:

```
UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
```

However there is information that must be included in the manifest:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#manifest

This will allow you to filter devices based on a number of attributes.